# C# regex. Optional match after string

Tags: c#, regex

I have an input like this `test1.test2.part01` which I want to strip away to `test1.test2`. The only thing i know is that it will end with `partxx` and probably a dot before the `partxx`. However, it will not always be a apart. Another example of input might be `testas1.tlp2.asd3.part10` which ofcourse should be stripped to `testas1.tlp2.asd3`.

I've made all that, no problem. The problem is the dot at the end before `partxx`. My regex at the moment is:

```
(.*)\.?part\d{1,2}
```

But it will include the dot in the group. I do not want the dot to be in the group. The below works as I want it, given that the dot exists, but it will not always be there.

```
(.*)\.part\d{1,2}
```

How can I exclude the optional dot from the group?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Escape the dot

```
(.*)\.?part\d{1,2}
```

The way you have it, the dot is interpreted as meaning "any character" rather than a literal dot.

Alternatively,

```
s/\.part\d\d?$//;
```

Comment: Thanks, can't believe I missed that. Even if I escape it it will be in the group

Comment: I suspect that this will still include the dot in the group since the quantifier inside the group is greedy. `(.*?)\.?part\d{1,2}` might work better.